# TRIGGER CON CONDICION

Tags: mysql, trigger

tengo un código donde intento hacer un insert a una tabla dependiendo del caso, para esto utilizo un triggers, todo estoy en MYSQL... necesito ayuda en la manera de elaborar el triggers ya que al ejecutar me sale error de sintaxis

acá el código:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_role after insert on users
        for EACH ROW
        BEGIN
        if new.tipo_usuario = 'ADMINISTRADOR' then 
            insert into model_has_roles(role_id,model_type,model_id) values (1,concat_ws(CHAR(92),'App','User'),new.id);
        end IF
        if NEW.tipo_usuario = 'EMPLEADO' then 
            insert into model_has_roles(role_id,model_type,model_id) values (2,concat_ws(CHAR(92),'App','User'),new.id);
        end IF
        if NEW.tipo_usuario ='CLIENTE' then 
            insert into model_has_roles(role_id,model_type,model_id) values (3,concat_ws(CHAR(92),'App','User'),new.id);
        end IF
        END;
```

Comment: Añade por favor el mensaje del error obtenido

Comment: En principio deberías cerrar cada `end IF` con punto y coma: `end IF;` Si sigue sin funcionar, agrega a la pregunta el mensaje de error pulsando en [edit]. En cuanto a la lógica, parecería más simple asignar un valor: 1,2 ó 3  en los `if` y escribir una sola consulta cambiando el primer `value` por ese valor asignado.

Comment: La sintaxis esta correcta, solo agrega los ; tras los IF's, hice unas pruebas y pude replicar el que creo es tu error: las columnas tipo_usuario e id deben existir en la tabla donde esta el trigger (users), verifica eso y nos cuentas.